# OrientDB - Result from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, database, select, orientdb

I have a database that has 2 V's classes ('User' that has 2 strings named Name and Surname ,'Cinema') and 2 E's classes ('isGoing' that has an Integer property named Day, 'Friend').
This select returns all the 'Cinema' that the 'Friend' of the initial Vertex are going on a specific day.

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing')[Day = 29].inV()) FROM #12:0
```

But now I need to get all the 'User' Name and Surname that are 'Friend' of the initial vertex, the 'isGoing' property Day and have the 'isGoing' Edge going from the 'User' to a specific 'Cinema' (let's say it is #14:0).
The expected result would be a list of: String 'Name', String 'Surname' and int 'Day'. Something like:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, Day FROM (SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing').inV()) FROM #12:0) WHERE @rid = #14:0
```

Is this possible in OrientDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT in.*,out.*,Day 
FROM (SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing')[Day = 29]) 
      FROM #12:0)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I just made some changes so it stays like

    `SELECT in.*,out.*,Day FROM 
    (SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing)) 
    FROM #12:0) WHERE in.Id = 10`

Comment: I'm trying to learn OrientDB, so I built a test database to try this out, because I don't understand the syntax.  Unfortunately, the parser didn't understand, either.  I'm guessing the syntax has changed from an earlier version of the software.  (I'm using 2.2.8.)  I get a generic message: `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Invalid script:Encountered " <FROM> "FROM "" at line. Was expecting one of: <EOF>, <SELECT> ...`